# How to disable a submit form button given a certain condition

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to disable a cancel button if the the record field "Status" is already recorded as cancelled. I already know how to disable a button but the problem is how would the jquery know that the record field "Status" is Cancelled.
Here Are the Codes

```
 @foreach (var rDetail in Model.Customers.ToList()) { 

      <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.DateEntry)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.DateStart)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.DateEnd)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.Status.Name)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.UserCode)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.DateModified)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => rDetail.Remarks)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "RoomReservation", new { id = rDetail.Id}, null) |
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CancelReservation", "Rooms", new { roomId = Model.Id, reservationId = rDetail.Id, methodId = 0})) {
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class ="cancelSubmit"/>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You want to make the button disabled when the status label is cancelled right? That too during render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the status is cancelled you can disable it in the Razor itself.

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "RoomReservation", new { id = rDetail.Id}, null);

  @if(rDetail.Status.Name.Equals("cancelled"))
  {
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class ="cancelSubmit" disabled/>
  }
  else
  {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("CancelReservation", "Rooms", new { roomId = Model.Id, reservationId = rDetail.Id, methodId = 0})) {
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class ="cancelSubmit"/>
        }
   }
    </td>
```

If you want to do it jquery way:-

```
$(function(){
$('.cancelSubmit').each(function(){
   if($(this).closest('tr').find('#Status_Name').text() === 'cancelled')
   {
       $(this).prop('disabled',true);
   }
  });
 });
```

or inside the function you could do :-

```
$(this).prop('disabled',
        $(this).closest('tr')
       .find('#Status_Name')
       .text() === 'cancelled');
```

Comment: Dude, you're a life saver. I used the razor method and it worked like a charm. Though I also tried the logic before but we differ on code syntax. I really need to increase my code dictionary on ASP.net MVC 4. Anyway, thanks again man.

Comment: Wow great, glad it worked. I just typed it in the editor itself, wasn't even sure syntax is right.. :)

Comment: Well, at first it didn't worked but your "cancelled" is in small letter "c" as for my records where on a big letter "C", after changing it, it worked ^^

Comment: Use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. i.e `rDetail.Status.Name.Equals("cancelled",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);` So case won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, something like this should work:

```
$('#Status_Name').on('keypress', function(e) { //I think that's how the XFor handlers format ids
    $('button_to_disable').prop('disabled', this.value === 'Cancelled');
});
```